# Linked Lists in C. error: conflicting types. Solution?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, content-length

i have the following struct defined:

```
typedef struct PList{
    Person person;
    struct PList *nextPerson;  //  set to NULL by default <<<<<
}PList;
```

and this method:

```
int length(struct PList* db){
    PList* cur = db;
    int size = 0;
    while (cur != NULL){
    ++size;
    cur = cur->nextPerson;
}
    return size;
}
```

> error: conflicting types for 'length' is being thrown at the signature for the length method.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a conflicting declaration or definition of `length` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: You have a function definition that does not match the function declaration signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That actually means that there is another function/declaration called `length` elsewhere in your source code structure that has a different function signature.

Find where `length()` function is defined, and pass correct structure objects to that function(either of type `struct PList` or `PList*`)

Comment: So you cannot have 3 methods that take as parameters different structs? Overloading it kindof..

Comment: No - not in C - you can in C++ though.

Comment: You cannot do function overloading in C. Its possible in C++ however

Comment: In C++, while you can technically overload a global function (such as length) for different class types, one would generally make length a method of the class.  So `foo.length()` is more idiomatic than `length(foo)`...*most* of the time.

Comment: yes but i don't think it's possible to do anything of the sort since C isn't Object Oriented. I also don't think it's actually possible to implement it using something like a general struct since i don't think anything like inheritance is implemented for structs.