# Conflicting types error message in linked lists program using C pointers and struct's

Tags: c, pointers, struct

#### Description

I'm trying to understand pointers, linked lists, structures and such in C. As a learning experience, I have written this small program, which:

- defines some basic structures and creates links between them, using structure pointers.
- iterates over the whole linked lists and prints out all variables.
- creates another structure, but doesn't insert it into the linked list.
- calls a function `insertEntry` which inserts a given struct between one element of the linked list and his direct follower.

#### What I've done so far:

- [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609875/linked-lists-in-c-error-conflicting-types-solution#13609930) says: "That actually means that there is another function/declaration [..]  elsewhere in your source code structure that has a different function signature."

  - I've checked for typos in the function definition, declaration and its call.
  - I've checked the amount and type of the parameters. Both parameters of `insertEntry` are always two structs of the same type.
- [This different Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023345/incomplete-type-struct-error-in-c#14023367) says: "You have forgotten to `#include "client.h"`, so the definition", but I've also checked that. Both the actual filename on the filesystem and the `#include`.

===> I don't get, where my error is.

---

**ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.h:**

```c
void insertEntry(struct entry, struct entry);
```

---

**ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.c:**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.h"

struct entry {
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

// clangtidy: conflicting types for 'insertEntry' [clang-diagnostic-error]
void insertEntry(struct entry given_entry, struct entry entry_to_insert) {

    printf("Print inside insertEntry method: %i\n", given_entry.value);
    struct entry *second_pointer = (given_entry).next;

    // entry_to_insert is now the element in the middle
    given_entry.next = &entry_to_insert;

    // the third element
    entry_to_insert.next = second_pointer;

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct entry n1, n2, n3;

    n1.value = 1;
    n1.next = &n2;

    n2.value = 32;
    n2.next = &n3;

    n3.value = 34242;
    n3.next = (struct entry *)0;

    struct entry *list_pointer = &n1;

    while (list_pointer != (struct entry *)0) {
        int printValue = (*list_pointer).value;
        list_pointer = (*list_pointer).next;
        printf("%i\n", printValue);
    }

    printf("--------------------\n");
    list_pointer = &n1;

    struct entry a;
    a.value = 999999;
    a.next = (struct entry *)0;

    // clangtidy: argument type 'struct entry' is incomplete [clang-diagnostic-error]
    insertEntry(n1, a);

    while (list_pointer != (struct entry *)0) {
        int printValue = list_pointer->value;
        list_pointer = list_pointer->next;
        printf("%i\n", printValue);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can start by describing what the actual error is and where it is.

Comment: @2501 i don't understand your response, the actual error message is included in the source code - where my linter/checking program complained.

Comment: You need to "forward-declare" the struct `entry` in your file `ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.h`, i.e. before the function declaration: `void insertEntry(struct entry, struct entry);`, that is put the following `struct entry;` before that function declaration.

Comment: @nibro ooh, that fixes my error, thanks! if you turn your comment into an answer, i'll upvote and mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: When I compile the header with GCC 6.3.0 (on macOS Sierra 10.12.3) and no warning options whatsoever, I get a message like: `In file included from chkhdr-2684.c:1:0:` —
`xyz.h:1:25: warning: ‘struct entry’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration` —
`void insertEntry(struct entry, struct entry);`.  If your compiler didn't generate such warnings, you need to get a better compiler, or turn on more warnings.  If you saw such warnings but didn't mention them in the question, then you most certainly should have done.

Comment: At this stage in your career, the compiler doesn't generate irrelevant warnings; warnings indicate errors in your code that need to be fixed.  If you're not sure why, by all means ask after checking the documentation, etc, but don't ignore warnings from the compiler.  (And, for GCC, use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` as a basic minimum; I add more flags than that and am not happy with code until it compiles cleanly under those options.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the suggestion, will do in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "forward-declare" the struct `entry` in your file `ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.h`, i.e. before the function declaration: `void insertEntry(struct entry, struct entry);`, that is put the following `struct entry;` before that function declaration.

The reason for this is because when the compiler encounters `insertEntry(struct entry, struct entry);`, it doesn't know anything about `struct entry`. By forward declaring `struct entry`, you "ensure" to the compiler that the `struct entry` is defined somewhere in a source file.

Comment: When a compiler encounters `struct entry` as parameter within function declaration, it already assumes, that `entry` is a tag name of struct of incomplete type. That is why it's legal to declare a pointer like `struct xyz *p = NULL` without _any_ prior declaration of `struct xyz`. The forward declaration may be considered a good practice, but it is not required. In both case, the type is incomplete, so one cannot pass arguments to such function nor access objects of such type within the current translation unit.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski I know that the type is incomplete and you could not access the definition of it if it was defined in another source file.

Answer (score 3):

You should place `struct entry` declaration in **ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.h** :

```c
struct entry {
    int value;
    struct entry *next;
};

void insertEntry(struct entry, struct entry);
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to define `struct entry` in `ex1_insertStructure_linkedList.h`, but just forward-declare it, which is better if you also strive for "information hiding".

Comment: @nbro True, but I don't think "information hiding" is something OP is looking for :)

Comment: @nbro Yes you do need to in this case, otherwise the function cannot be shared.

Comment: @2501 What do you mean by "the function cannot be shared"? You mean that `insertEntry` cannot be shared?

Comment: @nbro Other translation units won't see the definition of the struct and the code won't compile. The solution given by SegFault is correct in this case, yours only delays the problem.

Comment: @2501 Then, _in this case_, it's really **not** necessary since the main function is defined in the same source file where `struct entry` is defined. Btw, I'm not the delaying the OP's current problem. What you said is related to another problem, which is somehow related to the OP's current problem, but not the same.